# Android BetterPickers

Tags: android, interface, android-fragments

I'm currently trying to implement the Android BetterPickers library(https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers). I've been able to display the picker that asks the user to select the time, but method that the interface provides is not being called. The method is line 43 at https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers/blob/master/sample/src/com/doomonafireball/betterpickers/sample/activity/hmspicker/SampleHmsDefault.java.

Here is what my code looks like. The main difference between my code, and the sample provided is that my code is being executed in a Fragment as opposed to in an Activity(Line 35 in the github sample). I used getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager(). Why isn't the onDialogHmsSet method being called?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.hmspicker.HmsPickerBuilder;
import com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.hmspicker.HmsPickerDialogFragment.HmsPickerDialogHandler;
import com.example.hiittimer.R;

public class NewWorkout extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, HmsPickerDialogHandler {
    private View view;
    private Button btnSetOn, btnSetOff;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_new_workout, container, false);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    setViews();
    return view;
}

private void setViews(){
    btnSetOff = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_set_on);
    btnSetOn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_set_off);
    btnSetOff.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSetOn.setOnClickListener(this);



}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_set_on:
        HmsPickerBuilder hpb = new HmsPickerBuilder().
        setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment)
                    .setFragmentManager(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        hpb.show();


        break;

    case R.id.btn_set_off:
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDialogHmsSet(int reference, int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
    Assert.assertTrue(false);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The solution is at https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers/blob/master/sample/src/com/doomonafireball/betterpickers/sample/fragment/SampleTimeFragment.java

Answer (score 1):

add the .addNumberPickerDialogHandler(yourclassname.this) in your fragmentmanager
check the code bellow...it worked for me

```
FragmentManager fragManager = getFragmentManager();
NumberPickerBuilder npb = new NumberPickerBuilder()
    .addNumberPickerDialogHandler(CashTransaction.this)
    .setFragmentManager(fragManager)
    .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment_Light);

  npb.show();

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

In call NumberPickerBuilder you must set `setTargetFragment` :

> `this` or `fragment.this` - > current fragment    .

```
  NumberPickerBuilder npb = new NumberPickerBuilder()
                        .setFragmentManager(activity.getSupportFragmentManager())
                        .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment)
                        .setTargetFragment(this) // or .setTargetFragment(fragment.this)
                        .setLabelText(getString(R.string.day_c));
```